# Java deleting all occurrences of word in String

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

I am trying to remove the word "Bye" every time it appears in the String. It works for the first time "Bye" appears, but then begins deleting the wrong characters.

```
String str = "HiByeHiByeByByeHiHiHi";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    for(int i=0; i<str.length()-2; i++){
        if(str.substring(i,i+3).equals("Bye")){
            sb.delete(i,i+3);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Your changing the String as it's being iterated through by a for list, and so its length and position of chars are changing as you're doing this.

Comment: You better do this `"HiByeHiByeByByeHiHiHi".replaceAll("Bye", "")`

Comment: OOPS: "You're"!

Comment: Suggestion: learn to read Javadoc. Skim-read the Javadoc for *all* the classes in `java.lang` and `java.util`, and fully read the useful-looking classes. This would certainly include `String`. If you stick with Java you will eventually read all of this, so you might was well make a start, and you would have found `String.replaceAll()`

Comment: @slim thanks for the advice,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no need to use a StrinBuilder, `String#replace` can do that, just use the method [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
String str = "HiByeHiByeByByeHiHiHi";
str = str.replace("Bye", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use replaceAll.

```
String str = "HiByeHiByeByByeHiHiHi";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("Bye", ""));
```

It will print:

> HiHiByHiHiHi

Comment: why regex, you don't need a regex, just a simple replace can do the trick

Comment: @shanemcg If you are satisfied with this answer then please accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `String::replace` method, you can replace all the occurrence in one shot :

```
str.replace("Bye", "")
```

so you need just this :

```
String str = "HiByeHiByeByByeHiHiHi";
System.out.println(str.replace("Bye", ""));
```

**Outputs**

```
HiHiByHiHiHi
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problems in the code

- str is still used, but it's an invariant, it should be sb instead
- i must be decremented in case of delete or `if` changed by `while`

  ```
  String str = "HiByeHiByeByByeHiHiHi";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( str );
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < sb.length() - 2 ; i++ ) {
      while ( sb.substring( i, i + 3 ).equals( "Bye" ) ) {
          sb.delete( i, i + 3 );
      }
  }
  System.out.println( sb.toString() );
  ```